# Separate different values from a String array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, format

I have this String

> String st1= "1005 random array 2.2";

I just wondering about how can i separate this string array and assigning its values into:

1. an int variable "a" with the four first characters.
2. an string array with the 12 characters from "random array"

and one float variable with the 2.2 value.

Comment: We can at most give a solution that works for the string in the question, but there is no guarantee that it will work for the problem you are trying to solve in general.

Comment: `string array with the 12 characters from "random array"`. Do you mean char array, or do you actually want an array consisting of 12 String-literals that are one char long?

Comment: @nhahtdh i know sr :)

Comment: @PakkuDon an array...

Comment: Yes. Answers from users @ Lashane and @ Leos Literak went useful to me :) @KillerR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

direct answer:

```
final String st1 = "1005 random array 2.2";

final int idx1 = st1.indexOf(' ');
final int idx2 = st1.lastIndexOf(' ');    

final int a = Integer.valueOf(st1.substring(0, idx1)).intValue();
final char[] s2 = st1.substring(idx1, idx2).toCharArray();
final float b = Float.valueOf(st1.substring(idx2+1)).floatValue();
```

Comment: Helped a lot. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think following code? :-)

```
    String st1= "1005 random array 2.2";
    String a = st1.substring(0, 4);
    char[] stringArray = st1.substring(5, 12).toCharArray();
    float number = Float.valueOf(st1.substring(18));
```

Comment: Helped a lot. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
String st1= "1005 random array 2.2";
int a = Integer.parseInt(st1.substring(0, 4));
String stringArray = st1.substring(5,17);
double number = Double.parseDouble(st1.substring(18));
```

Comment: result will be `a=100` and `stringArray=random arra`

Comment: Yea you r right .. I corrected that answer...

Answer (score 0):

The First Thing You can Split String and Assign Values for variable.

```
String st= "1005 random array 2.2";
String  CArray[] = st.split(" ");
int i=Integer.parseInt(CArray[0]);
String s=CArray[1]+" "+CArray[2];


float f=Float.parseFloat(CArray[3]);

System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(f);
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer. I've already solved my rookie problem. However, thank you for your answer.